# How to link a button to tab in other page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, hyperlink, tabs

I had a list of tab. An example below is keluarga tab.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#profil">Profil</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#keluarga">Keluarga</a></li>
</ul>
//other codes here..
</div>
```

I want to link a button from another page using this button to keluarga tab, not profile tab.

```
  <a href="{{ url('view_profil')}}/{{$valueItemregistrationkeluarga->ItemRegistrationID}}#keluarga" class="btn btn-warning btn-md">Back</a>
```

I use javascript here to activate keluarga tab when the button is clicked.

```
 <script>

// Javascript to enable link to tab
 var hash = document.location.hash;
   if (hash) {
     $('.nav nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]').tab('show');
    } 

 // Change hash for page-reload
  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
   window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
 });
 </script>
```

However, it   giving an error in console:

```
 1288:2276 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function
```

showing this line of code is problem:

```
 $('.nav nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]').tab('show');
```

I had checked my jquery redundancy and try to eliminate any redundancy but still fail to avoid the error.

THis is my jquery list in the header:

```
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/ionicons.min.css') }}">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/jquery-ui.css') }}">
   <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.css') }}"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/select.dataTables.min.css') }}"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/buttons.dataTables.min.css') }}"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.css') }}"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('jquery/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css') }}"/>
 <!-- <script src="{{ asset('javascript/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>   -->


<!-- datatable -->
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
 <link href="{{ asset('adminlte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('adminlte/css') }}/select2.min.css"/>
 <link href<!-- ="{{ asset('adminlte/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href -->="{{ asset('adminlte/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

 <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
</script>
  <script
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
```

in javascript section:

```
 <!-- <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> - ->
 <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/jszip.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('javascript') }}/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <script src="{{ asset('javascript/custom.js') }}"></script>  
 <script src="{{ url('adminlte/js') }}/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('adminlte/js') }}/select2.full.min.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('adminlte/js') }}/main.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ url('adminlte/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('adminlte/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url('adminlte/js/app.min.js') }}"></script>

<script>
window._token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
</script>

 @yield('javascript')
```

I had tried other scripts also but the same error appear.

Why the script does not work? It link the button to the page but to profile tab (active default page). It does not directly link to keluarga tab

This console log:

```
  <script>  
 // Javascript to enable link to tab
 console.log($('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="#keluarga"]'));

 var hash = document.location.hash;
 if (hash) {
  $('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]').tab('show');

 } 
// Change hash for page-reload
 $('.nav-tabs a').on('show(n.bs.tab', function (e) {
window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
});
</script>
```

it returns:

```
jQuery.fn.init [a, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".nav.nav-tabs a[href="#keluarga"]"]
 0: a
 context: document
 length: 1
 prevObject: jQuery.fn.init [document, context: document]
 selector: ".nav.nav-tabs a[href="#keluarga"]"
 __proto__: Object(0)
```

Comment: Is that line meant to read `$('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]').tab('show');` ? (missing . between `.nav nav-tabs`)

Comment: the error refer to the code line..do not know what is wrong with the line. at first i am suspecting is doesn't get the jquery source.. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Assuming you're using jquery-ui, seems the function/method name should be `tabs` not `tab`, checking from the [api reference](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/).</strike>

Perhaps like so?

```
$('.nav nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]').tabs('show');
```

or

```
$('.nav nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]').tabs({ show:true });
```

Let me know if it works

Ok, seems you're just using Bootstrap `data-toggle="tab"` and just  activating it using jQuery. In your selector, are you sure that it's correct? Seems class `nav` and `nav-tabs` is in the same level, perhaps the selector should be like so

```
 $('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]').tab('show');
```

Also try to console.log `$('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]')` to check what's the returned value and whether it returns any element.

**Update** Seems you haven't included bootstrap.js in your html reference.
Please add it as so

```
...
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
 <link href="{{ asset('adminlte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ asset('adminlte/css') }}/select2.min.css"/>
 <link href<!-- ="{{ asset('adminlte/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href -->="{{ asset('adminlte/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- add bootstrap.min.js cdn -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
</script>
...
```

Comment: it still throwing the same error..can you guide e which jquery need to be used? I add up them as i add new features to the application

Comment: is it console.log(e);?

Comment: @joun you can console.log the returned elements from the jQuery selector, i.e. `console.log($('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]'))` and check whether there is any returned elements

Comment: i tried that, and it returns Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )..without console it still throw the same error as before..is there caused by conflict in jquery?

Comment: @joun how about this `console.log($('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="#keluarga"]'))`? This is just to check if the selector is correct.

Comment: the console log returns Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tab is not a function

Comment: @joun have you tried adding/calling this `console.log($('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="#keluarga"]'))` to your script or in the devtools? This will help us to check if the element can be matched and return results.

Comment: @joun also please pay change the new selector string in your script. I think the correct one should be `'.nav.nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]'` and not `'.nav nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]'`

Comment: @joun got it. In your script if you change this line `$('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]').tab('show');` to this `$('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="#keluarga"]').tab('show');` does it work? Also please try to add `console.log(hash)` inside your if block `if (hash) { ... } `

Comment: @joun I just noticed in your html reference, seems you haven't included bootstrap js. Please check my updated answer to add the script reference on your html head

Comment: jQuery.fn.init [a, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".nav.nav-tabs a[href="#keluarga"]"]
407:1917 #keluarga

Comment: <script src="{{ url('adminlte/js') }}/bootstrap.min.js"></script>---this is bootstrap js right?

Comment: @joun hmm yes, that should be the bootstrap. I tried the `tab` method for bootstrap + jQuery in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jb13zp5m/1/) and it seems to be working fine though

Comment: i think it is because jquery conflicts but don't know which one

Comment: for selecting tab in a same page it is working in my page..but the button link to activate certain tab is not working. it is using bootstrap only..